# How to pass GridView as a ConverterParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to pass the ListView or the GridView as a ConverterParameter
However, in the Converter routine the parameter is coming as a type string

Below is the part of the XAML List view and the Converter class.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!!!

```
    <ListView Name="SeqDtStDataListView1" Grid.Row="1" 
        DataContext="{Binding Path=DisplayDT[0], Converter ={StaticResource      
                                                       CNVToColumn},ConverterParameter=?????}"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        SelectionChanged="SEQDatalistview_SelectionChanged"  Margin="5"> 


       <ListView.View >
             <GridView x:Name="SeqDtStDataGridView1"/>
       </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Converter:

```
namespace MFTest.Converters
{
public class CNVToColumn : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value,
                          Type targetType, 
                          object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)value;
        GridView GV = (GridView)parameter;                <========= fail here ===========
        if (dt != null && GV != null)
          foreach (var colum in dt.Columns)               // Binding the Columns
          {
                DataColumn dc = (DataColumn)colum;
                GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn();
                column.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(dc.ColumnName);
                column.Header = dc.ColumnName;
                GV.Columns.Add(column);
          } 
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 21):

From .NET 4 onwards you could use [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx) which allows you to avoid a `ElementName` binding which can only be set on dependency properties while achieving pretty much the same thing.

Due to cyclical dependency restrictions you cannot reference a control inside itself or its ancestors in the tree. You can however move the binding up a level and just inherit the `DataContext`, e.g.

```
<Border DataContext="{Binding Path=DisplayDT[0],
                              Converter={StaticResource CNVToColumn},
                              ConverterParameter={x:Reference SeqDtStDataListView1}}">
    <ListView Name="SeqDtStDataListView1" Grid.Row="1">
```

Comment: *you cannot reference a control inside itself or its decendants *. You mean **ancestors**. You cannot reference ancestors.

Answer (score 7):

You can't bind to it.

ConvertParameter inherits from Object and therefore is not bindable.

You can, however, define your Binding in the code behind instead of doing it in the XAML part.

```
System.Windows.Data.Binding b = new System.Windows.Data.Binding();
b.ConverterParameter = this;
```

Please read about the limitations on the ConvertParameter [here](http://www.shujaat.net/2011/02/wpf-binding-converter-parameter.html)

Comment: @Luis Filipe - not sure about the the linked post. IMHO ViewModels should not contain any dependency properties.. I associate DPs more with Views/Controls rather than with view-agnostic ViewModels.

Comment: `ConverterParameter` doesn't inherit from anything, it's a property, the problem is that `MarkupExtension` does not inherit from `DependencyObject`.

Answer (score -3):

You could use `ConverterParameter={Binding ElementName=[insert x:Name of grid view]}`

Although IMHO I'd reconsider the need - do you really need to pass a UIControl as a Converter parameter?

Comment: At run time on the partial class this error popup: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'ConverterParameter' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: @IrmiMrm - Short answer.. you can't do that.. easily. You can only bind to DP properties on derivations of DependencyObject. Binding does not qualify - you're attempting to specify a Binding for the ElementName property of another Binding. Seems too convoluted.. a simpler solution to the problem must exist.